# Washer doesn't spin-dry anymore (most of the time)

Tags: washing-machine

**Update:**

I researched some more and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ovizK_bOrc) of exactly the same problem and some Amazon reviews which state it, too. I ordered an inverter and will replace it myself and update if it fixes the issue.

---

My Bosch WAS28443 washer doesn't spin-dry anymore. Well... most of the time anyway. I had a mechanic coming over (5min for 70€) who said it was the inverter and suggested a repair for 250€.
I don't really believe him, because I think the inverter is an on/off thing, and not "sometimes" or randomly.

It doesn't follow any pattern I could recognize. Yesterday I had a 6kg load and it worked flawlessly, today it was only light sports clothing ~1kg and it didn't work. Also, if I set it to spin only after it didn't work, sometimes it spins without further problems, sometimes it doesn't, no matter which speed, or any other settings are set up.

I uploaded a video (https://vimeo.com/224351376)  to show the problem. As I wrote, sometimes everything is in order, but most of the time it tries to spin, but can't/won't.

I think it sounds like a cog not having enough "grip", lacking a better term.

I'm thinking of opening the machine, but wanted to ask some maybe specialist if this is a good idea or if I just should get a mechanic.

Comment: What's the model number? Is there any pattern to when it works and when it doesn't - load size, spin speed, water temp, automatic cycle, etc?'

Comment: @mmathis thank you, I added the details. No pattern whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it obviously was the inverter. I ordered and changed it and after several cycles everything is well, it spins even better than before...